# What is our elevator pitch?

Tags: discussion

Suppose you have exactly **ten seconds** to describe this community to a stranger.

- What exactly do you say?
- What is it that we are all about?
- What's our motto, our tagline?

I'm very interested in hearing what others think a thoughtful answer to this would be.

Comment: Are we going for full-on corn here? Bastardizing some famous quote? Or do we want something a little more high-brow? Personally, I'm all for corny. I'll think about it today and report back...

Comment: I'd say corny is fine, as long as it's *accurate*. The tagline for the Cooking site stands out as being truly excellent: "Seasoned Advice". It's that perfect blend of corny, accuracy, and memorability (did I make that word up?).

Comment: "Practical Metaphysics"?

Comment: LOL. Very nicely done. :)